# The first parameter in withStyles() material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```js
const styles = theme => ({
    margin: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    }
});

StyledComponent = withStyles(styles)(Component);
```

I found a strange thing in this code, what is the value of the parameter theme? We only pass the function styles to withStyles HOC.

Comment: check the [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3a5dfa9ded218e4e1cdd42375a0eea0d19981076/packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js#L54). It accepts either a object or an object creator.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Material-ui will have a default theme that is passed to the styles in the `withStyles` function, if you do not provide one using [MuiThemeProvider](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#muithemeprovider).